# What is this "might well"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> If a minor episode of White House crow-eating over President Obama's absentee father's half-brother seems an unlikely event to derail a major piece of legislation, **it might well be** — at least by itself.
>
> -- *[theweek.com](http://theweek.com/article/index/253801/how-the-strange-case-of-obamas-uncle-omar-complicates-immigration-reform)*

I wanted to make sure.
Is this the same as "it is natural that it be an event to derail ...?"
Like "it should derail ..?"
It has every reason to derail this?

at least by itself ...means "This event alone should derail it, at least, if no other incident exists?

Comment: I didn't read that news yet. But it sounds like the White House seems to go back their own words about President Obama's absentee father's half-brother. This event shouldn't lead to the derail (of some legislation), but as it turns out, it seems to be likely (indicated by "might as well be"), with just this event alone ("at least by itself"). --I believe my understanding should be at least mostly correct, if not 100%.

Comment: "..., it might well be [unlikely ... to derail a major piece of legislation], at least by itself."  But in combination with other things, probably found later in the paragraph, it might be enough to derail a major piece of legislation.

Comment: So it means the opposite of my interpretation. That is, it may not derail the legislation?

Comment: That's how I read it.  But then, I did hit my head pretty hard this morning.

Answer (score 5):

*Well* here is used in the sense it usually has with modal verbs: *probably*.

The construction here is elliptical—the complement of *it might well be* is deleted because it is identical with the complement of *seems*:

> [**If** <sub>SUBORDINATOR</sub>]
>      [**a ... episode** <sub>SUBJECT</sub>]
>         [of ... half-brother <sub>ADJUNCT to SUBJECT</sub>]
>      ]
>      [**seems**<sub>VERB 1</sub>]
>      [an unlikely **event** <sub>COMPLEMENT of VERB 1</sub>
>         [to derail ... legislation <sub>COMPLEMENT of *unlikely*</sub> ]
>      ]
>   [*THEN* <sub>IMPLIED CONJUNCTION</sub>]
>      [**it** <sub>SUBJECT 2</sub>]
>      [**might** ...  **be**<sub>VERB 2</sub> might ... be 
>         [ at least by itself <>ADJUNCT to VERB 2] 
>       ]
>      [<s>an unlikely **event**</s> <sub>DELETED COMPLEMENT of VERB 2</sub>]
>         [<s>to derail ... legislation</s> <sub>DELETED COMPLEMENT of *unlikely 2*</sub>]
>      ]

It is not a well-thought-out sentence: the *if* is in the wrong place. What the author probably means is

> This episode seems too trivial to derail the President's immigration legislation, and it probably **would** be too trivial—if it were by itself. But ...

Answer (score 3):

> ***If a minor episode*** of White House crow-eating over President Obama's
>   absentee father's half-brother **seems an unlikely event to derail** a
>   major piece of legislation, **it might well be — at least by itself**. But
>   conservatives **were already wary about the same immigration judge's
>   decision to grant asylum to Obama's aunt**, Zeituni Onyango — Uncle
>   Omar's sister — in 2010. **And Uncle Omar has been nominated as a symbol
>   of Obama's immigration policy before.**

No, it actually means the opposite of what you think. It means that it **should not be** enough to derail the event. I've highlighted the context above.

This is what it actually says: *might well [**not**] be [**enough**]*

*Might well be* is speculation, and this is the subjunctive mood; but it's a negative statement because it's preceded by *seems an unlikely event to derail.* It goes on to say that it ***might well [not] be [enough]* on its own**, except there are other extenuating factors that may make enough to do so.

Otherwise, it wouldn't ordinarily be enough.

Comment: So, this alone won't make the derailment happen but, if there are other things, this might happen. Is this what this means?

Comment: @kih1930 Well, it's actually more definitive than it sounds. It's not a matter of ***if*** there are other things; there ***are, in fact, other things***. *Might well be* is acting as a modifier. It's qualifying *seems an unlikely event*, and *might well be* itself is further qualified by *at least by itself.*, which is then further qualified by the other events mentioned. I will do a re-write for you below:

Comment: I'm hoping that this will make it more clear; this is what it means in essence: ***If a minor episode seems an unlikely event to derail** a major piece of legislation, **it might well be — at least by itself**. [The opposition **was/had  [already] been] already wary [before because of a] decision to grant asylum to Obama's aunt**--Uncle Omar's sister--**[and because] Uncle Omar had previously been nominated as a symbol of Obama's immigration policy***.